# Nestjs Docker Debug

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, nestjs

I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN apk add --no-cache bash && npm install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:12.13-alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

my docker-compose is:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
      - 9229:9229
    command: npm run start:debug
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Inside my package.json and script, I have:

```
"start:debug": "nest start --debug 0.0.0.0:9229 --watch"
```

I added the conf in my visual Studio Code (.vscode/launch.json)

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Debug",
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 9229,
    "sourceMaps": true,      
    "restart": true,
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
    "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
  }
]
```

}

After that I can run `docker-compose up --build` and start my debugger but the code doesn't stop at my breakpoint.

I use Mac 12.6 and Docker version 20.10.13